# She said that, over time, they lose their ability to "full charge", or " fully charge"?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, nouns

> She said that, over time, they lose their ability to full charge.

why is the above sentence wrong?   FULL is adjective, FULLY is adverb, CHARGE is noun.
Isn't it adjective +noun, and adverb+verb(or adjective, or adverb)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In this case "charge" is a verb. More correctly it is the infinitive verb "to charge". It might be even better to say "[...] ability to charge fully." If you want to use "charge" as a noun you would have to change the sentence to something like this:

> She said that, over time, they lose their ability to reach full charge.

Comment: thank you, Smatterer, you are helped me with your kind answer, and thanks, Maryam to support my question to cleanly.   Good luck, You all.